# Is there a S.M.A.R.T. Library for .NET or Java?

Tags: java, .net, hardware, disk-smart

*I asked a somewhat [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123575/how-to-get-the-temperature-of-motherboard-of-a-pc-and-other-hardware-statistics) question but I want it to make it more concrete and 'programming' oriented, so here it goes:*

Does any body know, if there is a **.NET**, **JAVA** or any other Framework, library, .jar file or what ever: to access [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis,_and_Reporting_Technology) Statistics?

Thanks!

Comment: You should maybe reword your question, judging from the accepted answer you want this to work for windows only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get SMART statistics from .Net via the System.Management and WMI class "MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData".

Here is a short example that I created for you. Start a new console project and add a reference to the System.Management assembly, then paste this into Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace GetSMART
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "root\\WMI",
                "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData"
            );

            foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach( PropertyData prop in item.Properties )
                {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",
                    prop.Name, prop.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!... too bad it isn't Java hehe.

Comment: No problem. FYI, I just searched for Java WMI and there are a lot of articles out there.