# SNMP OID for CPU core temperature of Windows computer

Tags: snmp, temperature, oid

I am developing an Android app to retrieve some information from computer using SNMP. Is it possible to get the CPU temperature (or any temperature within device) by SNMP? If it is possible, what is the OID to access the info? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on HW and OS. For Linux servers you can use lm-sensors. lm-sensors supports temperature and fan speed on the motherboard. There is a MIB for lm-sensors. I have only used lm-sensors on SLES and there you have to download and install support for it.

I don't know if there is any support for lm-sensors on Windows. Maybe you can pick up something via WMI...?

If it is for a "real server" the vendor (HP etc) may have an SNMP agent and MIB already supporting this. Then it will probably work for both Linux and Windows.

See also [How to get the temperature of motherboard of a PC (and other hardware statistics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123575/how-to-get-the-temperature-of-motherboard-of-a-pc-and-other-hardware-statistics)